# threeJs wrong (too low) camera position

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, gltf

I am new to ThreeJS, what I am trying to accomplish is to load a gltf model, which is correctly shown in `three-gltf-viewer`, it is valid.

[image: model from gltf web validator]

When I load it into threeJS, the model loads up ok but the camera is placed on the horizon line of the model, and the orbit control does not work when I try to zoom in and out or any other rotation of the scene is disabled.

[image: model from threeJS]

I tried to tweak any possible values of camera and scene but I just can't "jump on top" of the model and see it from above. Here is the code.

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 800, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 500, 1500000 );
camera.position.set(1, 1, 1);

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ alpha: false });
renderer.setClearColor( 0xC5C5C3 );
renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement ); 
var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xcccccc );
scene.add( ambientLight );
var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
directionalLight.position.set( 0, 1, 1 ).normalize();
scene.add( directionalLight );      

// Instantiate a loader
var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
loader.load('GLTF_local_coord_sys/GEOTIFF_local_coord_sys.gltf', 
    function(gltf) {
        var object = gltf.scene;
        gltf.scene.scale.set( 0.65, 0.65, 0.65 );              
        gltf.scene.position.x = 1;                  
        gltf.scene.position.y = 1;                  
        gltf.scene.position.z = 1;                  

        scene.add( gltf.scene );
        camera.lookAt(scene.position);
    },
    function ( xhr ) {
        console.log( ( xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100 ) + '% loaded' );
    },
    function ( error ) {
        console.log( 'An error happened' );
    }
);
camera.position.z =25;
function animate() {
    render();
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
}

function render() {
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
render();
animate();
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: function ( error ) {
     de
     console.log( 'An error happened' );
}); might be the problem

Comment: Thanks for spotting it, actually that was a piece of comment (I removed) before posting the code, I removed it but still I have the same problem.